# PHP MySQL - String var in query not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I've been at this for a day, I'm hoping a different set of eyes could tell me where I'm going wrong.

We are archiving call center daily reports in MySQL, and I have a page that lets people search through them based on supervisor and day.  When they execute a search, two invisible text boxes retreive the search criteria, and when they hit "Export", those values are passed to an export page, that runs PHPEXCEL, to print their results.

It was working fine, but we recently pieced it into a PHPBB page, and for some reason it can't read the supervisor name string correctly.  So the search page works correclty, all the following code/info relates to the 'export' page.

```
echo $supervisorName;  #returns John Smith
```

Echoing that on the export page breaks the Excel file PHPExcel spits out, which makes sense, but it does demonstrate that the variable is being saved and is correct.

```
$sql = "Select   
newTeam, First, Last, `Calls Handled`, `Avg AHT`, ... 
From 
phpbb_reportarchive inner join employees on phpbb_reportachive.phonenum = employees.phonenum 
where 
employees.newteam = '{$supervisorName}' and phpbb_reportarchive.Date = '{$incidentDate}' 
order by last";
```

When i include the supervisor name in the string, though, PHPExcel spits out an empty result - no rows pasted.

However, if I remove the variable $supervisorName, and replace it with 'John Smith', it returns the expected result and PHPExcel gives me what I want.

I'd appreciate any help on this.  If I can provide more information to clarify anything I will.  Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Why is $supervisorName in curly braces?

Comment: Did you put the `echo $supervisorName` that printed the correct value immediately before assigning `$sql`? `echo $sql` and make sure that produces the correct query.

Comment: Reflix - my understanding is the braces are optional - I tried removing them, it didn't make a change.  Chicago - It looks like it's inserting a linebreak before the supervisor name, not sure why - but thanks for the great suggestion, hadnt thought to echo sql.  Im going to try to separate that out

Comment: Curlies can be used for clarity when parsing variables in a double-quoted string. For example, if you wanted to append characters after the value of `$supervisorName`, the curlies would be required (or you would need to concatenate strings with `.`). In your example, the single quote is not valid in a variable name, so PHP can interpret the variable correctly without the curlies. They're also useful if you want PHP to parse the index of an array or a property of an object. For more info, see [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I understood it was a way for clarifying when a variable ends and the rest of the statement begins, but that certainly clarifies it.  My impression is there isn't really a situation where using the curly braces would cause problems, so I'll likely make it a habit to use them all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the $supervisorName was being pulled with a bunch of trailing whitespaces and linebreaks.  I used trim to clean it up and it works perfect.  Thanks both of you, I would've been at this all day.